# How to install PyQt4 and PyQt5 at different virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to maintain 2 python projects. one of them is using PyQt4 and another one is using PyQt5. So I created 2 virtualenv as follow.

> 1) installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper by sudo
>
> 2) logout from root(sudo)
>
> 3) created virtualenv at /home/thura/workspace/python/virtualenv
>
> 4) mkvirtualenv gui_pyqt4 under
>   /home/thura/workspace/python/virtualenv
>
> 5) mkvirtualenv gui_pyqt5 under
>   /home/thura/workspace/python/virtualenv

And I want to install the lib/module/etc of PyQt4 into gui_pyqt4 and install the lib/module/etc of PyQt5 into gui_pyqt5. I tried to install "pip install python-qt4" and "pip install python-qt5" but not working.

How can I install different module into different environment.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the names on pypi to install a python package with `pip install ...`

After a quick search, pyqt4 was named `PyQt4` and pyqt5 was named `PyQt5`.

So please try

```
pip install PyQt4
```

in gui_pyqt4, and

```
pip install PyQt5
```

in gui_pyqt5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the appropriate virtual environment and then use the command `pip install PyQt4`or `pip install PyQt5`. Since you are using virtualenvwrapper, the virtual environment is activated automatically. Otherwise, use `workon virtualenv_name` to activate the environment.Do tell if the problem still persists.